Is the Van der Waals interaction anisotropic even for isotropic states?
I came to a puzzling conclusion when thinking through some atomic physics. I would be grateful if someone can explain where my reasoning may be going wrong, or tell me if I'm right. Here's my logic.

The dipole-dipole interaction is

$$
V_{dd} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \left[ \frac{\vec{\mu}_1 \cdot \vec{\mu}_2}{R^3} - 3 \frac{(\vec{\mu}_1 \cdot \vec{R})(\vec{\mu}_2 \cdot \vec{R})}{R^5} \right]
$$
Here $R$ is the internuclear separation between atoms, and of course $\vec{\mu}$ represents the electric dipole operator.

When the two interacting particles have the same quantization axis, the dipole-dipole interaction becomes

$$
V_{dd} = \frac{\mu_1 \mu_2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^3} \left( 1 - 3 \cos^2\Theta \right)
$$
Here $\Theta$ is the angle subtended between the internuclear axis and the quantization axis. This is similar to a scattering angle.

Suppose the two interacting particles are an atom in an $S$ state and another in a $P$. In the basis $\lvert SS\rangle$, $\lvert SP\rangle$, $\lvert PS\rangle$, and $\lvert PP\rangle$, I can use a couple of these basis states to write the dipole-dipole interaction energy as

$$
\langle SP\rvert V_{dd} \lvert PS\rangle = \frac{|\langle S\rvert \mu \lvert P\rangle|^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R^3} \left(1 - 3 \cos^2 \Theta\right) = \frac{C_3}{R^3} \left(1 - 3 \cos^2 \Theta\right).
$$
Here, $R$ and $\Theta$ factor out of the matrix element calculation since they are considered constant. Since $C_3$ is a pure number rather than a function of angle, this expression makes the anisotropy of the dipolar interaction explicit.

Now, for a Van der Waals interaction between two S orbital atoms (with the same quantization axis), one can use second-order perturbation theory. The interaction energy is

$$
\sum_{n_1,n_2} \frac{|\langle SS|V_{dd}|n_1,n_2\rangle|^2}{E_{SS} - E_{n_1,n_2}}
$$

$R$ factors out of the Van der Waals matrix element calculation to give the familiar $1/R^6$ dependence. I would also expect $\Theta$ to factor out for this same reason. That makes the Van der Waals energy

$$
\frac{C_6}{R^6} \left(1 - 3 \cos^2\Theta\right)^2
$$
Like with the dipole-dipole interaction, $C_6$ is a pure number, so this form makes anisotropy explicit.
It seems weird to me that isotropic $S$ orbitals can have these anisotropic interactions. I have seen references referring to the dipole-dipole interaction as anisotropic but none describing the Van der Waals interaction as such, so I find it puzzling that an angular function would end up in the dipole-dipole interaction but not in the Van der Waals interaction.
Can someone help clear up this apparent contradiction?

In 4., what are $n_1,n_2$? How are you getting $\Theta$ in there, if there are no $P$ states which could introduce it?

@JánLalinský: $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the states being summed over in perturbation theory. So any internal states to which the $S$ state has a dipole transition. And I'm not sure what you are asking about $\Theta$. It's the angle between the internuclear axis and the quantization axis.

Can you explain what is "quantization axis" in this context? Is it the arbitrary axis we choose to define our psi function basis, which $P$ is a member of? Then $\Theta$ depends on that choice. A randomly found system is unlikely to be in P state with direction which is the same as the direction we choose beforehand. So if you're calculating something that should not depend on description such as the choice of the axis, the result indeed can't depend on $\Theta$.

@JánLalinský: It's the axis about which the spin magnetic quantum number is defined. As an example, suppose for the dipole-dipole interaction case, one applies an external magnetic field along the direction of gravity and polarizes the atom in the $P$ state into $m_L = 1$. Then the external field is turned off, leaving the $z$ projection of the angular momentum aligned with gravity. So in this case there is a well-defined $\Theta$.

The states $n1,n2$ are anisotropic, like P states, right? So then shouldn't there be different $\Theta$ for different $n1,n2$? I do not understand how are you getting single $\Theta$ in the expression. There should be many different thetas, depending on the other non-S state in the matrix element integral...

@JánLalinský: I'm not sure why there would be different values of $\Theta$. There is a single quantization axis, which is defined by the experimental conditions I described before. There is a single internuclear axis, which doesn't change as a function of orbital quantum number. $\Theta$ is defined as the angle subtended by these two fixed axes. Note that $\Theta$ is not an angular variable of the wavefunction; rather it is closer to something like a scattering angle.

Since you mention van der Waals, I think your $\boldsymbol{\mu}_1,\boldsymbol{\mu}_2$ have to be electric moment operators, e.g. $\boldsymbol{\mu}_1 = \sum_a q_a(\mathbf r_a - \mathbf R_1)$, $\boldsymbol{\mu}2 = \sum_b q_b(\mathbf r_b - \mathbf R_2)$ where $a$ runs over indices for electrons in the atom 1, and $b$ runs over indices for electrons in the atom 2. If so, then I don't see how direction of orbital magnetic moment vector (quantization axis) can affect the operator $V{dd}$. I could see how one could be lead to this idea if $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ was interpreted as magnetic moment.

But as far as I know, theory of vdW interaction works with electric interaction of electric dipoles, it does not care for orbital magnetic moments or spins?

Yes, the $\vec{\mu}$ is the electric dipole operator. And if your reasoning were correct, then even the dipole-dipole interaction would be isotropic, and it is clearly not. If two permanent dipoles were interacting, the quantization axis would be the dipole orientation. In the case I mentioned, I am simply using the angular momentum projection as an example of a quantization axis that is physical and unchanging, allowing me to define a $\Theta$ without ambiguity.

Your mistake is considering only a single $P$ state.  There can be virtual dipole moments (generated by quantum fluctuations) in any direction, and this corresponds to virtual transitions to any possible $P$ state.  If you sum over all three $P$ states, you will get three terms, each with a different direction cosine term, and the sum $\cos^{2}\Theta_{1}+\cos^{2}\Theta_{2}+\cos^{2}\Theta_{3}$ is just 1, making the whole expression angle-independent.
The quantum fluctuations in the dipole moment of one atom produce a corresponding dipolar electric field.  This field then acts to polarize the other atom in the same direction.  This follows an essentially classical pattern, whereby the second atom develops dipole moment proportional to the fluctuational electric field of the first atom (a field with strength $\propto r^{-3}$ at the location of the second atom).  There is then a dipole-dipole potential between the two atoms.  The product of the dipoles is proportional to the square of the fluctuating dipole moment of the first atom, which means the lowest-order energy shift is second order.

Thanks for this. Presumably these virtual dipole moments arise in the dipole-dipole interaction, but they are negligible to first order? And we need to consider them in second order perturbation theory?

@ultracold See my edit.

Brilliant answer. Thanks for your time!
